# NSDateFormatter: Converting "5/13/2012 6:05am" (US, EDT) to "13/05/2012 12:05" (IT, GMT+1)

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am retrieving a time value from a server. The format is:

"5/13/2012 6:05am"

It is not specified in the string but I know it is "EDT".

I need to:

1) Get rid of the am/pm thing.

2) Convert it from EDT (or other timezone) to the local GMT+/-x time.

For my timeZone (Italy, GMT+1) it should become:

"13/05/2012 12:05"

How can I do this with NSDateFormatter?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale: [NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
```

...?

Thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you set your NSDateFormatters dateFormat to the source format. In your case:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy h:mma"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"5/13/2012 6:05am"];
```

This creates a new instance of NSDate. Now you set the formatters dateFormat to your target format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"];
NSString *myString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

You could also use two date formatters, one for converting you'r string into NSDate instance and one to convert it back to the corrected NSString.

For further informations and the complete list of the current format specs refer to the [unicode reference](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)